# HTML 5 Local Storage proper usage

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using the new local storage that html5 offers.
When my mobile app (using phonegap) runs, it first goes to the server to get a list of members. The list doesn't change very often, so I was thinking maybe to keep it in the local storage and just refresh it every week or so.
My question is if it's right to do so, because it's a list of 900 people. Not too big but also not small.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you konow the browser?  http://caniuse.com/#search=local

Comment: you can store 900 people object in localstorage instead of going every time to server to get it\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

900 people with (I guess) 5-6 fields for each one of them is around (did a test in my db with a text file) 45kb overhead. 
Most phones and tablets now can live with that. (Aka, putting a bigger image in the background is going to load your app more).

So go for it.